# clang duplicate symbols when including a .h file

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [obj-c duplicate symbol for header variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908222/obj-c-duplicate-symbol-for-header-variable)

I have multiple .m and .mm files in my project. I can include this .h file (that dosent have a corresponding .m or .mm file) in as many .m files as I like but when I include it in more than one .mm file I get the duplicate symbols linker error.

Also in the .h file I have surrounded the content with preprocessor commands (Are these respected in obj-c?) here is what it mostly looks like:

```
#ifndef _CONFIG_H_
#define _CONGIF_H_

CGFloat WIDTH, HEIGHT;
// other similar code...

#endif
```

I get the duplicate symbols error on WIDTH and HEIGHT

Comment: Header file variables are declared "extern" (as in `extern CGFloat WIDTH, HEIGHT;`) and in a **SINGLE** .c/.mm file declared *without* "extern" (what you have above). This tells the compiler that anyone including your header knows these symbols exist, and at link-time those references are fixed up to the globals you declared in the .c/.mm file. This is (i believe) the second-most-frequent C/C++ question asked on SO (templates in .cpp files being #1 I'm pretty sure) but for the life of me I can't nail down a solid duplicate example right now. Sorry about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [obj-c duplicate symbol for header variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908222/obj-c-duplicate-symbol-for-header-variable) **and also** [Struct with a value in a header file causing duplicate symbol linker error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206853/struct-with-a-value-in-a-header-file-causing-duplicate-symbol-linker-error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add

```
extern
```

keyword before CGFloat declaration in the header, and define the variables without extern in the .m file to avoid defining your variables in multiple places.

In the header:

```
extern CGFloat WIDTH, HEIGHT;
```

In a .m file (one of them, any one)

```
CGFloat WIDTH, HEIGHT;
```

Comment: @WhozCraig It's quite an abvious error, if you thinj about it a bit. `int var;` **defines** the variable, not only declares it. That's just the fault of functions that they can be declared without `extern` to actually be edtern.

Comment: @H2CO3 I *know* the error (see the comments under the OP). I was looking for a *duplicate* to reference and close this out, but I couldn't find a solid example, which shocks me considering how often this question is asked.

Comment: @WhozCraig Then you missed something... See my comment.

Comment: @H2CO3 That was *exactly* what I was looking for. Clearly I had way too wide a search pattern. thanks for the samples.

Comment: @WhozCraig Then why not vote for closure in this case? ;P